# Recursively deleting files within folders without prompting the user via Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm currently trying to remove all the files within a folder named *Local*. The script below does this, but it prompts the user in a PowerShell window. If  I append the `-Force` flag my script then removes all files within all folders. I'm not sure how  to remove all the files within the *Local* folder and not prompt the user. Below is the script in question.

```
$Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\folder1\folder2\"

Function Clear-Cache
{
    Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GI Studies' -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match "data\\local"} | % {del $_.FullName #-Force}
}

Clear-Cache
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why would it delete all files within all folders?

Comment: I don't want to delete all files within all folders, that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first do a recursive search for the directory(ies) from which to delete files, then do a non-recursive delete of the files in each of those.

```
Function Clear-Cache
{
    $localFolders = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GI Studies' -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match 'data\\local$'}

    $localFolders |% { dir $_.FullName -File | del -Force }
}
```

**Edit**
Use `FullName` of directory when searching for files

Comment: I believe this only works if you're running the script in the directory of the studies. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Clear-Cache
{
    $localFolders = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GI Studies' -Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match 'data\\local$'}

    $localFolders |% { dir $_.Fullname -File | del -Force }
}
```

Appending `.FullName` to the fifth line of your suggested code actually solved my problem. Thank you latkin for assisting me!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .NET Delete() function, it does not ask for confirmation:

```
$Path = "C:\folder"
$exclude = "file1.txt","file2.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include * -Exclude $exclude -Recurse | foreach {
    $_.Delete()
}
```